# Value of sum with primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Can anyone tell me the value of sum $\sum_p\left(\log p(\frac{1}{2p}-\psi(\frac{p+2}{2})+\psi(\frac{p+1}{2})\right)-\sum_n\frac{(\log(2^n)}{2^n}$ where $p$ ranges over prime powers and $n$ ranges from $1$ to infinity. $\psi$ is the digamma function.

Comment: Can it be computed by a computer

Comment: I think that $\psi$ part can be replaced by incomplete$ \ beta $function

Comment: Your brackets don't match. Can you fix that?